# What are the general merits and demerits of the post-PhD courses meant to groom junior faculty/researcher in finance/economics

Tags: postdocs, economics, training

What are the general merits and demerits of the post-PhD courses meant to groom junior faculty/researcher in finance/economics, similar to these?:

[Advanced Studies Program In International Economic Policy Research](https://inomics.com/program/advanced-studies-program-in-international-economic-policy-research-1219365)

[Max Weber Programme for Postdoctoral Studies](https://www.eui.eu/ProgrammesAndFellowships/MaxWeberProgramme)

Are they any good compared to top-notch postdoctoral fellowships in finance/economics?